# Loop inside (another) loop (not connected by ID) Smarty

Tags: php, arrays, templates, loops, smarty

Please, i need some help, i am new Smarty user, but i am stuck on this for about 5 days, please some experienced users help me.

Here is a example of the PHP code i am trying to convert: 
Code:

```
$numone = "1"; 
$contest = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `active`, `id`, `start`, `end`, `slots`,    `description`, `name`, `type`, `minimum`  FROM `contests` WHERE `active` = ?"); 
$contest->bind_param('i', $numone); 
$contest->execute(); 
$contest->bind_result($firstloop['active'], $firstloop['id'], $firstloop['start'], $firstloop['end'], $firstloop['slots'], $firstloop['description'], $firstloop['name'], $firstloop['type'], $firstloop['minimum']); 
$contest->store_result(); 


if ($contest->num_rows() >0){ 
 $n=0; 
 while($contest->fetch()){ 
 $n++; 
    if ($firstloop['active'] == "1") { 
        if ($firstloop['type'] == "0"){ 

     echo " 
     <table> 
     <tr><th colspan='2'>Contest name: ".$firstloop['name']." </th></tr> 
     <tr><th>Contest Start: ".$firstloop['start']."</th><th> Contest End: ".$firstloop['end']." </th></tr> 
     <tr><td>Description :<br> ".$firstloop['description']." </td></tr> 
             "; 

     $participants = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*), `uid` FROM `completed` WHERE `status` = ? AND `time` > ? AND `time` < ?  AND `payment` >= ? GROUP BY `uid` ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT ?");       
        $participants->bind_param('issii', $numone, $firstloop['start'], $firstloop['end'], $firstloop['minimum'], $firstloop['slots']); 
        $participants->execute(); 
        $participants->bind_result($counted, $secondloop['uid']); 
        $participants->store_result(); 

     echo " 
     <tr><th>Place</th><th>ID</th><th>Completed</th></tr> 
          "; 
         while ($participants->fetch()){ 

     echo " 
        <tr><td>".$n."</td><td>".$secondloop['uid']." </td><td> ".$counted."</td></tr> 
             ";          

        } 
     echo  " 
     </table>    
           "; 
         } 
      } 
   } 
}
```

And whatever i try i always fall at the end. Sad 
As you can see, the both loops are not connected by ID.

If someone can help me, will save me one more night without sleep. Thanks

Edit:  I fail in any attempt to convert into Smarty, i always get wrong results with the second loop, so i decide to post clean example of the loops, if someone can give me suggestions to convert this in smarty in right way.

Edit (Solved):
Thanks to dbone suggestion, about nested arrays with unique id passed to the second loop. (check the dbone post).
Thanks

Comment: Am I the only one how can't see any smarty code here?

Comment: @hek2mgl - As i say i fail in any attempt to convert into Smarty, i always get wrong results with the second loop, so i decide to post clean example of the loops, if someone can give me suggestions to convert this in smarty in right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the query values into nested arrays.  Doing just the queries in PHP, load them into a single variable to be sent to the SMARTY engine.  Add a setup at the beginning to clear the variable (error checking):

```
$to_smarty = NULL;
```

Then do the same code you are already doing but set the $to_smarty variable up as an array with the unique id from the first query (here I'm assuming $n, but you could use "name"):

```
 if ($contest->num_rows() >0){ 
  $n=0; 
  while($contest->fetch()){ 
  $n++; 
     if ($firstloop['active'] == "1") { 
         if ($firstloop['type'] == "0"){
             $to_smarty[$n] = firstloop
```

This will store all of that data into an array that can be passed to SMARTY.  When you do the second query, create a new index in the $to_smarty variable and populate that with the new values for each entry in the original array:

```
 $participants = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*), `uid` FROM `completed` WHERE `status` = ? AND `time` > ? AND `time` < ?  AND `payment` >= ? GROUP BY `uid` ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT ?");       
 $participants->bind_param('issii', $numone, $firstloop['start'], $firstloop['end'], $firstloop['minimum'], $firstloop['slots']); 
 $participants->execute(); 
 $participants->bind_result($counted, $secondloop['uid']); 
 $participants->store_result();
 $i = 0;
 while ($participants->fetch()){
      $to_smarty[$n]['participants'][$i]['n'] = $secondloop['uid'];
      $to_smarty[$n]['participants'][$i]['uid'] = $secondloop['uid'];
      $to_smarty[$n]['participants'][$i]['counted'] = $counted;
      $i++;
```

You can now pass the $to_smarty variable to the SMARTY engine to print the information with a template:

```
 $smarty->assign('stuff', $to_smarty);
 $smarty->display('template.tpl');
```

The template could look like this:

```
 {if $stuff}
 <table>
 {foreach $stuff as $first}
 <tr><th colspan='2'>Contest name: {$first.name} </th></tr>
 <tr><th>Contest Start: {$first.start}</th><th> Contest End: {$first.end}</th></tr> 
 <tr><td>Description :<br>{$first.description}</td></tr>
 <tr><th>Place</th><th>ID</th><th>Completed</th></tr>
 {foreach $first.participants as $participant}
      <tr><td>{$participant.n}</td><td>{$participant.uid}</td><td>{$participant.counted}</td></tr>
 {/foreach}
 {/foreach}
 </table>
 {/if}
```

The key is using nested, associative arrays.  (watch out for my typos, :-) )

Comment: Thanks dbone, you saved me from heart attack. I manage to work like a charm now. I will edit my first post and give you a credit.